# Why are there two implementations for retrieving the component type of an array-class?

Tags: java

Java 1.1 introduced [`Class#getComponentType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType()) which

> Returns the {@code Class} representing the component type of an array.
> If this class does not represent an array class this method returns null.

Since Java 12 there is also [`Class#componentType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#componentType()) which is semantically equivalent (as also specified in its documentation).

> Returns the component type of this {@code Class}, if it describes an array type, or {@code null} otherwise.
>
> ...
>
> Equivalent to {@link Class#getComponentType()}.

#### My Questions:

- Which one should I use? Neither of them is deprecated as of Java 21.
- Why does this happen? The function is so simple that there seems to be no implementation specific benefit.

Comment: Note that the "new" method `componentType()` comes from the [`TypeDescriptor.OfField<F>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/TypeDescriptor.OfField.html) interface, which the `Class<T>` class implements.

Comment: Which would raise the question why the new interface-method doesn't take over the name of the old one, which was there from day one.

Comment: They probably left the old method there for backwards compatibility.

Comment: ["Why" questions like this are not good questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/5133585) You can keep asking "then why is *that* the case?" ad infinitum (and in fact [you just did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77692498/why-are-there-two-implementations-for-retrieving-the-component-type-of-an-array#comment136969356_77692498)). Please make it very clear what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: The first question: "Which one should I use?"

Comment: You can use either, because as [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#componentType()), they are equivalent, so asking which one to use is also opinion-based.

Comment: @k314159 Asking why something is designed a certain way is considered opinion-based on Stack Overflow in general, even if it is documented somewhere, and that is not necessarily because of the question itself, but because those questions usually attract a lot of non-authoritative opinions, and rarely attract authoritative answers.

Comment: From my point of view the question isn't opion based just because of the why as shown by the answers: Why the new method? -> Because of TypeDescriptor.OfFields existence.

Comment: @xtay2 That is not the question you asked. You asked "what to use?" (opinion) and "why does this happen" (also opinion). And the follow-up question you can ask for the answer "Because of TypeDescriptor.OfFields existence" would then be "Why doesn't TypeDescriptor.OfFields use `getComponentType()` instead of `componentType()`" (also opinion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find that 12 version introduced not only `Class#componentType()` but also `Class#descriptorString()`, `Class#arrayType()` that reflects a new convention regarding method names. So, possibly, the old `Class#getComponentType()` can be deprecated and removed afterwards to deal with the duplication.

Summarize, in case the code will definitely not be running on JRE earlier than 12 version it's reasonable using new methods.

Comment: In jdk? removed something from `java.lang.Class`? right...

Comment: Though in theory, `getComponentType()` could be deprecated and eventually removed, I think this is unlikely to happen. For one, it would likely break a world of existing reflection code, and a lot of other methods follow the `getXXX` naming convention (which makes `Class` usable/introspectiable as a JavaBean).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel exactly, this is not possible to be a correct answer

Comment: the reason could be that if they used the same method, they might have unnecessarily tie the implementation in _both_ places. What if in future the implementation required for `TypeDescriptor.OfField::getComponentType` has to be different then the one from `Class::getComponentType`?

Comment: @Eugene, plausible `getComponentType()` will never be removed, but the cleanups happen sometimes: [Removed APIs in JDK 9..21](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/migrate/removed-apis.html)

Answer (score 4):

> Which one should I use? Neither of them is deprecated as of Java 21.

Use `getComponentType()`, just as you always have.

> Why does this happen? The function is so simple that there seems to be no implementation specific benefit.

Because, as Progman pointed out, as of Java 12, Class implements the TypeDescriptor.OfField interface.  The new method is required to implement it.

This happens from time to time and it is normal.  For example, String has both a `subSequence` method and a `substring` method.  One of those methods exists so that String conforms to the CharSequence interface.

If your code is not referring to objects using the TypeDescriptor.OfField type, there is no reason to make use of componentType().  Just keep using the same `getComponentType()` method as before.